# Why does manual focus styling appear on mouse click and default focus styles does not?

Tags: html, css, accessibility

So I've noticed that if I create my own focus styles for (for example) a button, the styling will show after I've clicked the button with a mouse. But when I click a button with default focus styling, there is no outline.

However, you can perfectly tab through the buttons and both of them will show an outline when in focus.

I'm very curious of why default focus styling and my own focus styling does not function in the same way. **Why does both appear on keyboard navigation, but only one of them appear on mouse click?**

Please try out both clicking and navigating with keyboard on these buttons:

```css
button {
  padding: .5rem;
  margin: 2rem;
}

.my-button:focus {
  outline: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">
  This button has default focus styling
</button>

<button type="button" class="my-button">
  This button has my own focus styling
</button>
```

PS: I'm not interested in any javascript hacky solutions, or removing the focus styling in any way. I just want to learn why the web works this way.

Comment: This is only true in some browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome uses `outline-style: auto`

[This is defined by CSS specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-ui-3/#outline-color) as follow:

> The `auto` value permits the user agent to render a custom outline style, typically a style which is either a user interface default for the platform, or perhaps a style that is richer than can be described in detail in CSS, e.g. a rounded edge outline with semi-translucent outer pixels that appears to glow. As such, this specification does not define how the outline-color is incorporated or used (if at all) when rendering `auto` style outlines. User agents may treat `auto` as `solid`.

This means that not all browsers consider that `solid` and `auto` are the same.

And you can reproduce the same behaviour as Chrome using the `auto` value rather than `solid`:

```css
button {
  padding: .5rem;
  margin: 2rem;
}

.my-button:focus {
  outline: 3px auto red;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">
  This button has default focus styling
</button>

<button type="button" class="my-button">
  This button has my own focus styling
</button>
```

Comment: I can't get this example to work. When navigating with a keyboard the outline is not red. I also tried only changing the "outline-color: red" but with no luck.

Comment: @m.trl I tested it with Google Chrome 62.0.3202.94 and 63.0.3239.84. Which browser do you have?

Comment: Version 63.0.3239.84

Answer (score -1):

By default, the outline property is an accessibility tool for keyboard users. Using the mouse, the cursor is your visual aid to know what element has the focus. Tabbing through a screen filled with elements without an outline visible will cause the user to lose track of where he has tabbed to (this is why you should [never remove the outline](https://a11yproject.com/posts/never-remove-css-outlines/) completely).

Comment: This is not an answer to my question. Please read more carefully.